# oracle.adfmf.application does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

[image]Which library I need to add to classpath to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This issue might be because of java version compatability. I have resolved by changing the compatable java version in Projet properties.

**Steps to do:**

Right click project -> <kbd>Project Properties</kbd> -> <kbd>Libraries and Classpath</kbd> -> under Java SE version click <kbd>Change</kbd> -> select "MAF JDK 1.8 Compact 2 Profile from <kbd>user</kbd> sub-branch.

Do the same step for both **ApplicationController** and **ViewController**, below is the screen shot for reference.

[image]

Below is the screen shot for list of library details which is attached along to the selected Java version,
[image]

Hope this solves your problem..!!